# Unity (Android Studio) duplicate entry error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

After I export my Unity project to Android Studio I cannot create release build (but it works perfectly for debug build)

I have next error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: io/fabric/unity/android/BuildConfig.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

It caused by this two lines in my build.gradle file:
`compile project(':fabric-init')`
 compile project(':fabric')

So, if I comment one of them it works good, but I need both of them

in 'fabric' I have io/fabric/unity/android package name
in 'fabric-init' I have io/fabric/sdk/android package name

So, package names are different. 
So why I have an error when using both? Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and when I add "minSdkVersion 19" to build.gradle it worked for me, but this means %73.9 of Android devices can run the app.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```